# Why does Traffic Layer always use cache?

Tags: caching, google-maps-api-3, traffic

I made an app that shows Google maps with the Traffic Layer. The problem I have is that it always shows the traffic layer in the cache, so it is completely useless. I need the cache for other stuff.

How can I prevent the Traffic Layer from using the cache without completely disabling it from the app?

Comment: Where are you, Google support??

Comment: what type of app did you made? Android, IOS, native or hybrid? what type of cache do you mean also?

Comment: posting some code would help us debug your issue and help you better

Comment: @albanx The tags mention the javascript API. What he means by cache is that he is unable to force-refresh the traffic layer so that newer information is available.

Comment: @Youssef this is not code-related. It is an issue with the API not providing a way to prevent caching of the data.

Comment: @LuisA.Florit I suggest that you open a new [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype:Javascript3) as this doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: Good suggestion @MrUpsidown! I'm going to live with Sergio's dirty hack for now.

Answer (score 4):

As i already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25687831/refreshing-google-maps-api-v3-layers/27904920#27904920), there seem to be no legal way to update traffic layer, even maps.google.com page don't autoupdate it. But i've found *dirty hack* that makes thing work - updating tile images manually:

```
function reloadTiles() {
    var tiles = $("#map-canvas").find("img");
    for (var i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++) {
        var src = $(tiles[i]).attr("src");
        if (/googleapis.com\/vt\?pb=/.test(src)) {              
            var new_src = src.split("&ts")[0] + '&ts=' + (new Date()).getTime();
            $(tiles[i]).attr("src", new_src);                                                   
        }               
    }
}
```