# Google Maps Relevant information retrieval

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to figure out what are the services Google API is providing. Meanwhile, I came to know about Traffic API. Can anyone tell me how frequently it updates the data ??
I am not sure whether it responds real time traffic data..I looked into Google Maps JavaScript API and also looking for Google's service which can provide me these details i.e. Current Traffic moving speed, Traffic Jam details, etc..

Comment: I tried to google it.. However I got 50% success only. 
I also need to get road types (i.e. Highways, Express ways, Rural area), special speed zones, etc. 
Can you please help me finding these details.. I worked for around 2 days, but I could not retrieve all these details..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I dug around a bit for an answer on this, and the best I can find is that it is indeed nearly 'real-time' or 'continuously'. They appear to aggregate it from a number of sources, including iPhone users (https://googleblog.blogspot.ca/2009/08/bright-side-of-sitting-in-traffic.html, https://www.quora.com/How-does-Google-Maps-collect-real-time-traffic-data, http://shreerangpatwardhan.blogspot.ca/2011/06/where-does-google-get-its-live-traffic.html).

Seems to be a fluid thing that is probably updating nearly every second (or less).

When you do the initial layer request, it says it gets that layer ["for the time the request is made"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/trafficlayer). Just FYI for if you need things to [stay updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25687831/refreshing-google-maps-api-v3-layers).

Comment: I tried to google it.. However I got 50% success only. 
I also need to get road types (i.e. Highways, Express ways, Rural area), special speed zones, etc. 
Can you please help me finding these details.. I worked for around 2 days, but I could not retrieve all these details..
Thanks in advance

Comment: @iCoder upvoting an answer when someone did research for you would be a good idea. Further to that, your comment is off-topic in regard of your question. **And** this site is not meant for asking others to do research for you.

Comment: @MrUpsidown I updated my question content, however I forgot to update that title. But it was not off tracking.. !!
I expected few more informations.. So added that in the question